# 2 questions regarding program in C Programming - Absolute Beginner's Guide

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

In C Programming - Absolute Beginner's Guide chapter 18, example 2, the program writes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
    int i;
    char msg[25];

    printf("Type up to 25 characters and then press Enter...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        msg[i] = getchar();
        if (msg[i] == '\n')
        {
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }

    putchar('\n');

    for (; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        putchar(msg[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 questions regarding the program.

1. msg gets allocated an array of 25 characters and printf tells the user to type up to 25 characters. Shouldn't msg then be allocated an array of 26 characters to accommodate backslash zero?
2. When the for loop is written like this: for (; i >= 0; i--), what is the start expression?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are right that a string would need one more byte for the terminator.

   But the program never treats it as a string, so that's a moot point.
2. There is none.

   None of the expressions in the C for-loop are obligatory.

   As a case-in-point, the idiomatic infinite loop:

   ```
   for(;;) /* Do things */;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. No, since this is not a c string and you know the size of the array, which happens to be 25, and can hold 25 elements.
2. Nothing is defined in the for loop. We use the variable `i`, defined at the start of main, and the value it holds is the value we reached when inputting characters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By c string, do you mean the string data type? I understand that it can hold 25 elements, but shouldn't one of them be used to accommodate the backslash zero? If the printf asks the user to input messages up to 25 characters, no space is left for the backslash zero.

Comment: @freesushi By a c-string I mean an array characters that are null terminated. You don't need space for a zero, because you know the size of the array( 25 ) in advance, and you are not storing a c-string.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there is a bug in this program if the user inputs more than 25 characters before pressing Enter. In that case, the first `for` loop ends with the value of `i` equal to `25`. In the second `for` loop, you will end up accessing `msg[25]`, which is accessing `msg` out of bounds.

`i` should be decremented after the `for` loop, not inside the `if (msg[i] == '\n')` block.

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    msg[i] = getchar();
    if (msg[i] == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }
}

i--;
```

Comment: I tried out your version in my appliance and it made a lot of sense to me. Thank you for your reply! But I don't understand what you mean by "you will end up accessing msg[25], which is accessing msg out of bounds" Why is msg[25] out of bounds when I have allocated 25 spaces in my msg array?

Comment: When an array is of size `N`, the valid indices are `0` to `N-1`.